# ¿Por qué no actualiza estado en WS al cerrar app con gestor de aplicaciones?

Tags: java, android, webservice

Tengo una función que manda un aviso al WS con el que conecto en mi aplicación en el estado `onDestroy()` para colocar al usuario logueado actualmente como offline. El usuario es desconectado (0 en la base de datos del WS, 1 para conectado). Esto funciona si uso el botón de atrás del sistema (sea físico o virtual), entonces se supone que la actividad pasa por `onDestroy()`. Cuando mato la actividad a través del gestor de aplicaciones actuales (Borrar todo, o individualmente), en el WS no cambia el estado.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    USER_IS = 0;
    Log.i("¿Usuario conectado?", USER_IS + "");
    callLogState(USER_IS);
}
```

Comment: Revisa la documentación, en cuanto a "onDestroy() ¡no cuente con que se llame a este método como un lugar para guardar datos!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que usas el método [**onDestroy()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy())  pero en realidad debes usar el método [**onStop()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) , revisa la documentación para ambos métodos:

> [**onStop()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) Llamado cuando ya no eres visible para el usuario. A
>   continuación, recibirá onRestart (), onDestroy () o nada, dependiendo
>   de la actividad posterior del usuario.
>
> [**onDestroy()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) Realiza cualquier limpieza final antes de que se
>   destruya una actividad. Esto puede suceder porque la actividad está
>   terminando (alguien llamado `finish()` en ella) o porque el sistema
>   está destruyendo temporalmente esta instancia de la actividad para
>   ahorrar espacio.
>   **Nota**: **¡no cuente con que se llame a este método como un lugar para
>   guardar datos!** Por ejemplo, si una actividad es la edición de datos en
>   un proveedor de contenido, esas ediciones se deben confirmar en
>   `onPause()` o `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` e incluso `onStop()`, no aquí.

Para guardar datos puedes realizarlo usando `onPause()`, en tu caso `onStop()` o incluso usar `onSaveInstanceState()`

Answer (score 0):

Colocar la función en `onStop()` me funcionó, supongo que cuando está en `onDestroy()` ya las variables y métodos no están en memoria. Quisiera me aclararan eso.